# Loading 3 elements after every button on click in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently trying to add question answer based system using jquery. I want to show 3 question at a time and after clickikng next button another 3 question comes .

Here is HTML

```
<div class="questions">

    <div class="question"> <div class="button-start">Start</div></div>
    <div class="question hide"> Q No 1</div>
    <div class="question hide"> Q No 2</div>

    <div class="question hide"> Q No 3
         <a class="button-next">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div class="question hide"> Q No 4</div>
    <div class="question hide"> Q No 5</div>

    <div class="question hide"> Q No 6
        <a class="button-previous">Previous</a><a class="button-next">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div class="question hide"> Q No 7</div>
    <div class="question hide"> Q No 8</div>
    <div class="question hide"> Q No 9
        <a class="button-previous">Previous</a><a class="button-next">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div class="question hide"> Q No 10</div>
    <div class="question hide"> Q No 11</div>
    <div class="question hide"> Q No 12
        <a class="button-previous">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="question hide"> Q No 13</div>
    <div class="question hide "> Q No 14</div>
    .........
    ......
    ...
</div>
```

I tried using Jquery like this .

```
<script>
    $('.btnStart').click(function(){
                $('.questionContainer:lt(3)').fadeIn(500);
                $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500);
                     questionsStatus.text("");
                     return false;

            });  
     $('.btnNext').click(function(){
                $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500);
                $('.questionContainer:gt(3)').fadeIn(500);
            });      
</script>
```

But the problem is Start button is working but i could not get next and previous button work . I tried using lt gt not working :(

Comment: `.questionContainer` ,  `.btnStart` elements not appear at `html` at Question ? What is `"button-start"` ?

Comment: `"button-start"` add class? should be `<div class="button-start">Start</div>` i guess. fix typo?in question or in code?

Comment: @Pekka Guest123...
ok . At first all the elements are hidden . But only Button name start is shown . After clicking Start that start button disappear and Q no 1 , 2 and 3 gets loaded . After that the button next is seen in Q No 3 . After clicking next button question 1 ,2,3 disappear and 4 ,  5 , 6 appears.

Comment: ahh ok fixed that typo in question .

Answer (score 1):

Try The [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3jnoqzet/).

I have updated the javascript code as below

```
$(function () {

    $('.button-start').click(function (e) {
        $('.question:lt(4)').fadeIn(500);
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.button-next').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).closest('.question').index();
        $('.question:lt('+(index + 4)+'):gt('+index+')').fadeIn(500);
        $('.question:lt('+(index + 1)+'):gt('+(index - 3)+')').fadeOut(500);
    });

    $('.button-previous').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).closest('.question').index();
        $('.question:lt('+(index - 2)+'):gt('+(index - 6)+')').fadeIn(500);
        $('.question:lt('+(index + 1 )+'):gt('+(index - 3)+')').fadeOut(500);
    });

});
```

As per your HTML, i have replaced the below selectors

1. `$('.btnStart')` to `$('.button-start')`
2. `$('.btnNext')`  to `$('.button-next')`

Also added the **previous** button functionality.

Hope this helps ...........